# How to include 2 class names in a addClass() method in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to include two classes as mentioned below..But it is not working.Could anyone look into the issue and suggest me a solution.

```
$('.list_Person .Skills').addClass("active");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to add two CSS classes, or add one CSS class to all elements met by two selectors?

Comment: Not to judge, but you really couldn't figure this out by reading the documentation for the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) and [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `comma` to achieve what you want. It is called as `multiple selector`.

Try,

```
$('.list_Person,.Skills').addClass("active");
```

---

If you want to add more than one class to a particular selection,just insert a space between the set of classes and then add it,like below:

```
$('.class').addClass('class1 class2 class3');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add two new class to a selector

```
$('.class1').addClass("class2 class3");
```

and if you want to add two class in selector

1. both class should be there

   ```
    $('.class1').filter('.class2').addClass('class3');
   ```
2. either one class

   ```
    $('.class1,.class2').addClass('class3');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.list_Person').addClass("active").addClass("Skills");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are just jquery begginer and want to select `.active` elements

```
$('.active').addClass("list_Person Skills");
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding two classes

```
$('.list_Person .Skills').addClass("active active2");
```

For adding In two classes

```
$('.list_Person,.Skills').addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can separate multiple classes with the space:

```
$('.list_Person .Skills').addClass("active secondClass thirdClass");
```